# regex negative lookahead identify url

Tags: regex

I have a few URLs that I would like to match. They are always following the same pattern:

```
name.url.com
name-dev.url.com
name-qa.url.com
```

Following this pattern I have 4 groups that I want to identify: ALL, LIVE, QA, DEV

ALL is pretty simple:

```
^[a-z-_]+\.url\.com$
```

QA and DEV are following the same pattern:

```
^[a-z-_]+dev\.url\.com$
^[a-z-_]+qa\.url\.com$
```

What I'm struggling with is to identify only the live urls. I know that it can't have qa or dev as a word. But the following isn't working:

```
^[a-z-_]+(?!dev|qa)\.url\.com$
```

The problem seems to be the first character set. How can I archive this?

Comment: What language are you using this regex in? Please update the tags for the question.

Comment: post some examples for live url's..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to make use of a lookbehind assertion here, if you can:

```
^[a-z-_]+(?<!dev|qa)\.url\.com$
```

This asserts that the top-level of the URL isn't preceded by `dev` or `qa`. [Here's a demo](http://regex101.com/r/wW0yG9).

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:(?!\bdev\b|\bqa\b).)+\.url\.com$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/20

Comment: Hey, [your post showed up in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6002688). Might want to complete the answer by adding details and addressing the question.

Comment: thank you, but it was working a little bit to greedy. was also matching white spaces inside the url.